# Rename SAS variables containing special characters

Tags: sas

After I imported a huge Excel file containing thousands of data into the SAS, I found some variables showing names with special characters. For example, I have variable names like "pre.tal" and "miss.auto.t0". SAS doesn't allow me to proceed with the statistical analysis due to the special characters in these variable names. I tried the following codes but failed to work. Any ideas? Thanks

```
options validvarname=any;
data one;
set one;
rename pre.tal_month_t0 = 'prenatal_month_t0'n;
run;
```

Comment: Always use "variable"n on names with special character. Try this: `rename 'pre.tal_month_t0'n = prenatal_month_t0;`

Comment: If a variable name contains no special character, you don't need to use "variable"n pattern any more.

Comment: You are literally applying the name literal syntax backwards.  Use on the name that is not a valid SAS name, not for the name that is a valid SAS name.

Answer (score 2):

It is the name with special characters that needs quotes and an "n":

`rename 'pre.tal_month_t0'n = prenatal_month_t0;`

And by the way, if you want to see your original names in listings, you can assign a label to variables

```
data one;
   set one;
   rename 'pre.tal_month_t0'n = prenatal_month_t0;`
   label prenatal_month_t0 = 'pre.tal_month_t0';
proc print data=one labels;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are pressed for time, change the option to `validvarname=v7`. SAS will automatically make variable names with letters and numbers while replacing special characters and whitespace with underscores. Then you don't have to worry about using name literals (`'...'n`).

Answer (score 1):

Using options validvarnames=v7; which will allows to use

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).